# Can't find any element using CSS selector with Selenium on Python

Tags: python, css, selenium

I'm running a script on vodafone.co.uk but I can't find any element using the CSS Selector.

```
browser.get("http://freesim.vodafone.co.uk/")
 browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#frmNew > div:nth-child(32) > div > div > div > div.freesim-text-last.last > button > span").click()
```

And this is what I get:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element
```

Doesn't metter what CSS I use, selenium doesn't find any element anyways. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us  which element does this represent "#frmNew > div:nth-child(32) > div > div > div > div.freesim-text-last.last > button > span" ?

Comment: Wow that got to be the most complicated css celector I have seen. Yes please tell us what you want to click and we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not mentioned about which element you want to interact with it.

I'm clicking on broadband link on `vodafone.co.uk`.

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://freesim.vodafone.co.uk/")

broad_band = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='https://www.vodafone.co.uk/broadband/index.htm'] button"))) 

broad_band.click()
```

You can write the same thing for your web element.

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#frmNew > div:nth-child(32) > div > div > div > div.freesim-text-last.last > button > span")))  
button.click()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I managed to solve this by finding the element after changing frame

Comment: @Beter: Okay , was this answer helpful ?

Comment: @Beter : Thank you. Have a nice day !